# ¿"Más bueno" es incorrecto, correcto bajo ciertas circunstancias o totalmente correcto pero poco usado?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática

En portugués brasileño *mais grande* (*más grande*) es aparentemente un error garrafal, solo bajo ciertas circunstancias no lo es, pero nadie me da una respuesta del porque. Hasta ahora mi conclusión es que este "error" es resultado de un capricho.

Me apareció la duda si *más bueno* en español es considerado un error, desde un punto de vista puramente lógico no lo es (según mi opinión). He revisado un poco pero no he encontrado alguna respuesta que no me deje dudas. ¿*Más bueno* es totalmente correcto?

Comment: "desde un punto de vista puramente logico" ¿Qué quiere decir eso? Un idioma tiene su propia lógica. La lógica del español es que "más bueno" se dice "mejor".

Comment: Claro, cada lenguaje tiene sus sistemas lógicos, en este caso me refiero a la gramática y si está correcto gramaticalmente entonces seria bueno también discutir la interpretación formal. Yo no he estudiado gramática de forma intensiva por eso es difícil contestarme a mí mismo.

Comment: Digamos que "más bueno" está bien construido, desde el punto  de vista lógico/gramatical. Pero el Español ya tiene una palabra para esa construcción particular ("mejor"), y esta es tan relevante que se impone a la construcción general.

Comment: Es mejor poner ese comentario como respuesta.

Comment: "más poquito" ...

Comment: La frase me suena inteligible, podría recomendarse _más cortito en cantidad_ pero yo no tendría problema en decirla, aunque últimamente me siento demasiado permisivo con el español. Gracias por la discusión.

Comment: es perfectamente correcto http://www.hispanoteca.eu/Foro-preguntas/ARCHIVO-Foro/Bueno-m%C3%A1s%20bueno-mejor.htm no anden inventando.

Comment: A mi entender es lógico, pero forzado, es decir, poco natural, no se usa, ¿Quién habla así?, claramente es un coloquialismo, porque en le hablar culto no tiene lugar, pero de que se entiende se entiende.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[El DPD dice lo siguiente:](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=bueno)

> 2.Existen dos formas para el comparativo de bueno:
>
> a) ***mejor***. Procede del comparativo latino *melior* y se usa en todos los
>   significados de bueno antes referidos, aunque en los sentidos de
>   ‘bondadoso’ y de ‘gustoso o apetecible’ se emplea con preferencia *más
>   bueno* (→ b):[...]
>
> b) ***más bueno***. Se emplea con preferencia a *mejor* para formar el
>   comparativo de bueno en el sentido de ‘bondadoso’: «Nunca he conocido
>   a nadie más bueno que él» (Valladares Esperanza [Cuba 1985]). También
>   es correcto su empleo para formar el comparativo de bueno en el
>   sentido de ‘gustoso o apetecible’: «Algunas personas piensan que,
>   cocidos [los garbanzos] en la misma agua del remojo, salen más buenos»
>   (Domingo Sabor [Esp. 1992]).

Resumiendo, en general se debe usar "mejor", salvo cuando se usa *bueno* con los significados de "bondadoso" o "gustoso o apetecible".

Comment: Sí es cierto, aunque no responde totalmente mi pregunta, coloqué las tres posibles opciones para abarcar un mayor número de personas, lo que no responde es si está totalmente correcto el uso de _más bueno_ en lugar de _mejor_ para cualquier uso del comparativo. Por ejemplo, podría usar _esta idea es más buena_ en lugar de _esta idea es mejor_.

Comment: Lo que yo entiendo de lo que dice el DPD es que se puede usar, y de hecho se usa más, *más bueno* en los casos de *bondadoso* y *apetecible*. Para todos los demás, hay que usar *mejor*. Es decir, "más bueno" es correcto como comparativo de bueno sólo cuando *bueno* se usa en sentido de *bondadoso* o *apetecible*.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con la interpretación de @MikMik: *más bueno* no puede usarse con ningún sentido salvo esos dos.

Comment: Yo no entiendo la recomendación de la RAE como una prohibición, creo que es una recomendación. Simplemente no me gustan las prohibiciones sin explicación lo que lleva a juzgar mal a las personas que usan las formas menos frecuentes, los ejemplos que di me suenan perfectamente bien con las reglas gramaticales del español, aunque no soy un experto, más bien me parece que tienen un significado relativamente diferente. Solamente estoy tratando de quitarme una duda.

Comment: Yo tampoco soy experto. Sin embargo, el hecho de que en 2b explique un uso y luego diga "también es correcto [otro uso]" da a entender que el resto de usos no son correctos. Por otro lado, que algo "suene bien" o parezca "lógico" no quiere decir que sea correcto. El español está lleno de casos irregulares, excepciones, etc. que lo hacen totalmente ilógico muchas veces. ¡Que se lo digan a los niños! Cuántas veces dicen cosas como "no **cabo*" o "eso está **abrido*". Es totalmente "lógico", pero también incorrecto.

Comment: En mi experiencia, tanto lo que dice la RAE como lo que explica MikMik casan perfectamente con el uso que oigo en España, al menos. No recuerdo haber oído nunca a un español usar *más bueno* con otro sentido que esos dos.

Comment: Entonces esa es la respuesta. En cuanto a lo de _"cabo"_ y _"abrido"_ son incorrecto mientras nos parezca así, en una pregunta sobre _jalar_ y _halar_ supongo que  _jalar_ debió ser incorrecto y ahora aparece como coloquial, en México y Centroamérica (de donde soy) no creo que se considere coloquial. Un amigo criticaba mucho el no uso de la tilde  en _"o"_ cuando estaba entre números y ahora la RAE lo prohíbe. Pensé que sí podía ser usado porque _"más bueno"_ podría dar a entender que las cosas que se comparan son buenas mientras con _"mejor"_ no necesariamente son todas buenas.

Comment: @Helmut "[...] son incorrecto mientras nos parezca así". Esa es la cuestión, que en español qué es correcto y qué no es "por convención". Algo es correcto si los hablantes, escritores, etc. lo usan así. Por eso, el comparativo de *bueno* es *mejor* (salvo en los dos casos indicados), porque el uso de "más bueno" no está lo suficientemente extendido para considerarlo como uso habitual y correcto.

Comment: en cuba se usa mucho decir `eso esta mas bueno que el carajo`

Answer (score 1):

Solo se usa en tres ocasiones, 
"Ese muchacho es ***mas bueno*** que aquel"
"Ese muchacho es ***mas bondadoso*** que aquel"
"Ese plato es ***mas apetecible*** que el otro"
Y porque? Simplemente porque decir :
"Ese muchacho es mejor bueno que aquel"
"Ese muchacho es mejor bondadoso que aquel"
y "Ese plato es mejor apetecible que el otro" son disparates. 
O sea, para entender cuando usas bien una o la otra manera gramatical, mira a ver como se ve en ambas formas y si te parece un disparate como los anteriores, entonces usas mas y el adjetivo. Si no parece oírse como disparate, usa mejor. La definición de mejor es mas que.

Comment: Desde luego _«mejor bondadoso»_ o _«mejor apetecible»_ son incorrectos.  Las frases alternativas serían _«Ese muchacho es mejor que aquel»_ o _«Ese ṕlato es mejor que el otro»_, en contraste con _«Ese muchacho es más bueno que aquel»_ o _«Ese ṕlato es más bueno que el otro.»_

Answer (score 1):

No, porque *"ese muchacho es mejor que aquel"* no nos dice en qué es mejor. Y lo que se ha mencionado aquí es que es más "bondadoso", y para indicar eso hay que decir "más bueno".

No soy española pero así me parece lógico.

Answer (score -3):

El que lea esto le digo, decir "más bueno" en lugar de "mejor" es la mayor burrada que puede cometer y es una pena que la "irreal academia de la lengua Española" lo acepte, pero entiendo que tienen que justificar sus astronómicos salarios y tienen que inventarse alguna novedad para no perder sus puestos de trabajo.
Ejemplos de uso: Yo soy bueno, fulano es mejor que yo, sutano es el mejor.
En el caso de referirse a la "cualidad de bondad" bueno-bondadoso es suficiente con decir "El es bueno o El es bondadoso" es una estupidez comparar dos personas bondadosas diciendo fulano es más bueno/bondadoso que zutano.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Échale también un vistazo a otras preguntas y respuestas. Procura responder realmente a la pregunta y recuerda que el formato adecuado puede servir para hacer tu respuesta más fácil de leer y entender. No dudes en pedir ayuda si lo necesitas. Bienvenido de nuevo. ¡Espero seguir viendo contribuciones tuyas en el futuro!